# Why the promise data requested from server is undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, promise, response

I am trying to get values from an ASP .NET Core API and then display them in a html page using Angular and Typescript. The request and response from server are working correctly. The response is an object and i tried to use a model class to get the values from the response.

The problem is when i try to display the values, all of values are undefined. I think the problem is with the Promise.

This is the response i got from server:

```
Id: 1
Name: "asd"
Description: "asd"
Syntax: "Typescript"
IdentityString: "karma"
LastModified: "2020-01-05T00:51:00"
Content: "asd"
FileId: 1
File: null
```

And there is the code:

**fileshare.ts**

```
export class FileShareComponent implements OnInit {


    constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: UserService,
    private http: HttpClient
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const file: string = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('file');

    this.http.get(this.service.BaseURL + '/Share?IdentityString=' + file)
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => this.service.sharedFormData = res as ShareModel);
            console.log(this.service.sharedFormData);
  }
}
```

**ShareModel.ts**

```
export class ShareModel {
    Id:number;
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
    Syntax: string;
    IdentityString:string;
    LastModified: string;
    Content: string;
    FileId: number;
}
```

**service.ts**

```
sharedFormData:ShareModel;
```

fileshare.html

```
<pre><code class="hljs">Name:
{{service.sharedFormData.Name}}</code></pre>
<pre><code class="hljs">Description:
{{service.sharedFormData.Description}}</code></pre>
<pre><code class="hljs">Syntax:
{{service.sharedFormData.Syntax}}</code></pre>
<pre><code class="hljs">LastModified:
{{service.sharedFormData.LastModified | date: "HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy"}}</code></pre>
<pre><code class="hljs">Content:
{{service.sharedFormData.Content}}</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `console.log(this.service.sharedFormData);` inside `then()`.

Because right now it executes before response was received.

And it looks like your `service.sharedFormData = undefined` on the moment `ngOnInit()` is called. But I'm not sure... But if I'm right, then that's is the reason for error messages. Because `this.service.sharedFormData = res` happens much later. (The same thing as with `console.log(this.service.sharedFormData)`) But before that Angular already tries to render your HTML with `service.sharedFormData = undefined`

Comment: That didn't work, i make an edit to this post so i added the html for more clarification.

Comment: @Eduard, What exactly did't work? Is `console.log()` inside `then()` still prints object with `undefined`s? Or it prints correct data, but it's not displayed on a HTML page? And it you moved console.log(), then update your question with this change.

Comment: The console.log() works, thanks. The problem is the values are not displayed on the HTML page. More exactly: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined.

Comment: I suppose the `service` your pass to the constructor of `FileShareComponent` initially have no object `sharedFormData`? And by "when i try to display the values, all of values are undefined." your meant that particular error message, and not that `this.service.sharedFormData = { Name: undefined, Description: undefined, ...}` ?

Comment: Try using ngIf on sharedFormData

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra, yes, that should help. But I think it whould be better for Eduard to pinpoint the issue, not to steer away from it :)

Comment: @x00 IMO that is the solution not a hack. I shall elaborate when on desktop ~ mobile not conducive for longer answers.

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra I'm not saying it is not, I'm just saying - if something works, but you do not know how, then it is not **the** solution, it's **a** solution